# How to generate SQL query to get a list of users who are in a few groups and not in some other groups

Tags: sql

Let say we have a table  like this one.

```
UserID | GroupID
u1 | G1
u2 | G1
u3 | G2
u1 | G2
u1 | G4
u1 | G3
```

How to generate an SQL query to verify   -> is a user 'U1' is in G1 and in G2 but not In G4"
This logic could be dynamic. So could be -> if user 'U1' is in G2 and not in G3

So basically I need to verify if "logic" returns true or false , for "logic" recorded in this way :

return users if they are in `(@Gr='gr1' or @Gr='gr2') and @gr<>'gr3'`

Hope i explained it right :)

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, I understood your question correctly.

Kindly check the below query, this can work if you have defined no of groups,
alter the where condition according to your need.

e.g.  `to verify -> is a user 'U1' is in G1 and in G2 but not In G4`

```
select * from
(
select UserID,
sum(case when GroupID = 'G1' then 1 else 0 end) g1_sum,
sum(case when GroupID = 'G2' then 1 else 0 end) g2_sum,
sum(case when GroupID = 'G3' then 1 else 0 end) g3_sum,
sum(case when GroupID = 'G4' then 1 else 0 end) g4_sum
from
table
group_by UserID
)
where UserID = 'u1' and g1_sum > 0 and g2_sum > 0 and g4_sum = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic as written could be accomplished with sub queries.
You would require the IN clause to do it that way.
Notice the usage of table aliases *(ug2 ug3)* to query the same table for each sub query

```
SELECT ug1.UserID  
     , ug1.GroupID    
  FROM [UserGroupTable] ug1
 WHERE (ug1.UserID IN ( SELECT ug2.UserID      
                          FROM [UserGroupTable] ug2
                         WHERE ug2.GroupID IN ('G1','G2')
                      ) 
       )
   AND (ug1.UserID NOT IN ( SELECT ug3.UserID                           
                              FROM [UserGroupTable] ug3
                             WHERE ug3.GroupID IN ('G3') 
                          )
       )
```